# AngularJS - ng-repeat not showing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Having some trouble displaying objects from an array into my page using ng-repeat.

I've used angular before for a similar task and have used the same kind of structure where I've loaded the controllers and ng-repeat elements in the HTML, but can't get the example below to work.

Can anyone see what might be stopping the content from showing?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWYXMx.

HTML:

```
    <body ng-app="portfolioApp" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">

    <div id="logo">

        <a href="index2.html"></a>

        <img src="img/logo-basic-dark.png" alt="Logo">

     </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        

                </button>

            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">

                <ul class="pull-right nav navbar-nav" id="socialNav">

                    <li class="socialIcon"><a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></span></a></li>

                    <li class="socialIcon"><a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></span></a></li>

                    <li class="socialIcon"><a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-lg"></span></a></li>

                </ul>

                <ul class="pull-right nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#home" alt="Home Button">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#about" alt="About Button">About Me</a></li>

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#skills" alt="Skills Button">My Skills</a></li>

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#work" alt="Work Button">My Work</a></li>

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#contact" alt="Contact Button">Contact Me</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </nav>

    </div>

    <main data-simplebar>

        <section id="home">

            <div class="sectionContent">

                <h1 id="intro">Home Intro</h1>

            </div>

        </section>

        <section id="about">

            <div class="sectionContent">

               <div class="row">

                   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">

                        <h1>About Me</h1>

                        <p>About Description</p>

                   </div>

                   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">



                   </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </section>

        <section id="skills">



        </section>

        <section id="work" ng-controller="projectsController">

           <div class="sectionContent">

                <div class="project col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="project in projects">

                   <div>

                        <h2>{{project.name}}</h2>

                        <h4>{{project.description}}</h4>

                        <a ng-href="#">View Project</a>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </section>

        <section id="contact">

            <div class="sectionContent">



            </div>

        </section>

    </main>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7758cac280.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@2.1.0/dist/simplebar.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="js/navScroll.js"></script>

</body>
```

JS:

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('portfolioApp', []);

app.controller('projectsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.title = 'Projects';
    $scope.projects = [

        {
            name: 'Name1',
            description: 'Description1',
            link: '#'
        },

        {
            name: 'Name2',
            description: 'Description2',
            link: '#'
        },

        {
            name: 'Name3',
            description: 'Description3',
            link: '#'
        },

        {
            name: 'Name4',
            description: 'Description4',
            link: '#'
        }

    ];

}]);

});
```

Comment: You are not executing the IFEE function ... Replace `(function(){...}); ` with  `(function(){...})(); `

Comment: Also, you're loading in your scripts multiple times (angular, jquery, bootstrap)

Comment: devqon - Only forgot to remove them from HTML code after loading directly through Codepen itself, didn't have any effect

Comment: Aby feedback or suggestions nick?

Answer (score 0):

Check the working code below

```js
var app = angular.module('portfolioApp', []);

app.controller('projectsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Projects';
    $scope.projects = [
        
        {
            name: 'Name1',
            description: 'Description1',
            link: '#'
        },
        
        {
            name: 'Name2',
            description: 'Description2',
            link: '#'
        },
        
        {
            name: 'Name3',
            description: 'Description3',
            link: '#'
        },
        
        {
            name: 'Name4',
            description: 'Description4',
            link: '#'
        }
        
    ];
    
}]);
```

```css
 /* GENERAL TEXT STYLING */

 ::selection 
 {
  background:#1C16F6;
  color:#fff;
 }

 ::-moz-selection 
 {
  background:#1C16F6;
  color:#fff;
 }

 ::-webkit-selection 
 {
  background:#1C16F6;
  color:#fff;
 }

 a, p, input, textarea, h1, h2, h3, h4
 {
  color: #272930;
 }

 a, p, input, textarea
 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Heebo', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }

 h1, h2, h3, h4
 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 }

 a
 {
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
 }


 /* GENERAL LAYOUT */

 html, body 
 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }

 main
 {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
 }

 #logo
 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 99;
 }

 #logo > img
 {
  height: 25px;
 }

 #logo > a
 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 /* NAV */

 nav,
 .navbar-default
 {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 90;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 30px 30px 0 30px;
 }

 .nav > li > a,
 .nav > li > a:focus
 {
  background: transparent;
  color: #272930;
  font-size: 13px;
 }

 #navbar .navbar-nav li > a
 {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
 }

 #navbar .navbar-nav li > a:focus
 {
  color: #777;
 }

 #navbar .navbar-nav .active > a,
 #navbar .navbar-nav .active > a:focus
 {
  color: #272930;
  background: transparent;
 }

 #navbar .navbar-nav#socialNav li > a
 {
  margin: 0 10px;
 }

 #navbar .navbar-nav#socialNav li > a:first-of-type
 {
  padding-left: 0;
 }

 #navbar .navbar-nav#socialNav li > a:last-of-type
 {
  padding-right: 0;
 }


 /* SECTIONS */

 section
 {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 99;
 }

 section:nth-of-type(even)
 {
  background: #fdfdfd;
 }

 .sectionContent
 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 }


 /* HOME SECTION */

 #home h1#intro
 {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #272930;
  width: 80%;
 }


 /* ABOUT SECTION */

 #about
 {
  
 }


 /* WORK SECTION */

 #work
 {
  height: auto;
  background-image: url('../img/work.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
 }

 #work .sectionContent
 {
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
 }

 #work .project
 {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all linear 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 0.1s;
 }

 #work .project > div
 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
 }

 #work .project:first-of-type:hover
 {
  background: rgba(130, 160, 72, 0.9);
 }

 #work .project:nth-of-type(2):hover
 {
  background: rgba(193, 100, 144, 0.9);
 }

 #work .project:nth-of-type(3):hover
 {
  background: rgba(69, 156, 140, 0.9);
 }

 #work .project:nth-of-type(4):hover
 {
  background: rgba(241, 137, 76, 0.9);
 }

 #work .project h2
 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all linear 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 0.1s;
 }

 #work .project h4
 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition: all linear 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 0.1s;
 }

 #work .project:hover h2,
 #work .project:hover h4
 {
  color: #fff;
 }

 #work .project a
 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1.5px solid #777;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #777;
 }

 #work .project a:hover
 {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1.5px solid #272930;
  color: #272930;
 }


 /* CONTACT SECTION */

 #contact
 {
  
 }
```

```html
     <body ng-app="portfolioApp" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">
 
    <div id="logo">

        <a href="index2.html"></a>

        <img src="img/logo-basic-dark.png" alt="Logo">

     </div>
  
    <div class="container-fluid">
   
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        

                </button>

            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">

                <ul class="pull-right nav navbar-nav" id="socialNav">

                    <li class="socialIcon"><a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></span></a></li>

                    <li class="socialIcon"><a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></span></a></li>

                    <li class="socialIcon"><a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-lg"></span></a></li>

                </ul>

                <ul class="pull-right nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#home" alt="Home Button">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#about" alt="About Button">About Me</a></li>

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#skills" alt="Skills Button">My Skills</a></li>

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#work" alt="Work Button">My Work</a></li>

                    <li class="navLink"><a href="#contact" alt="Contact Button">Contact Me</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </nav>
    
    </div>
    
    <main data-simplebar>
        
        <section id="home">
           
            <div class="sectionContent">
                
                <h1 id="intro">Home Intro</h1>
                
            </div>
            
        </section>
        
        <section id="about">
           
            <div class="sectionContent">
               
               <div class="row">
               
                   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
                
                        <h1>About Me</h1>

                        <p>About Description</p>
               
                   </div>
                   
                   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                       
                       
                       
                   </div>
                
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </section>
        
        <section id="skills">
           
            
            
        </section>
        
        <section id="work" ng-controller="projectsController">
           
           <div class="sectionContent">
                
                <div class="project col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="project in projects">
                   
                   <div>
                    
                        <h2>{{project.name}}</h2>

                        <h4>{{project.description}}</h4>

                        <a ng-href="#">View Project</a>
                    
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </section>
        
        <section id="contact">
           
            <div class="sectionContent">
                
                
                
            </div>
            
        </section>
        
    </main>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7758cac280.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@2.1.0/dist/simplebar.js"></script>
    
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    
    <script src="js/navScroll.js"></script>
    
</body>
```